# multiple pdf files with html2pdf

Tags: php, pdf, html2pdf

I need to create multiple PDF file from a php loop... any ideas on how to do that?
I try to use html2pdf but I get a tag error (the include file is working fine beacuse the single output is working!):

```
require_once('html2pdf.class.php');
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) { 
$id=$row['id'];
       include('pdf.php');
        $content = ob_get_clean();
        try
        {
    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'en', false, 'ISO-8859-1'); 
    $html2pdf->setTestTdInOnePage(false);

    $html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
            $Filename = "PDF_".$id.".pdf";
            $html2pdf->Output($Filename, 'F');
        }
        catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
            echo $e;
            exit;
        }
      }
```

**ERROR I get:**

```
File : /var/www/html/eco/_class/parsingHtml.class.php 
Line : 117 HTML code invalid, a tag is closed too many times: <table> 
HTML : ...</table> </td> <...
```

If I add **ob_start();** before the include:

```
TCPDF ERROR: Unable to create output file: PDF_.pdf
```

Thanks

Comment: write the  error please

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exact error messages that you're getting. Make sure the line of code which is triggering your error is included in your question, and indicate which line it is.

Comment: This may be caused by improper HTML which is not compatible with `html2pdf`. I suggest you to use `mPDF` instead as it has improved these functions a lot.

Comment: that means I have to redo the all PDF/php file... it's a very complicated one and is working well if taken without the loop..

Answer (score 1):

Once again I solved on my own... Anyway I would like to post the solution for someone who will get the same problem:

```
require_once('html2pdf.class.php');
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY id ASC");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) { 
ob_start();
<page>
.... HTML ....
</page>
         $content = ob_get_contents();
        try
        {
    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'en', false, 'ISO-8859-1'); 
    $html2pdf->setTestTdInOnePage(false);
    $html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
    $Filename = "../folder/".$name.".pdf";
    $html2pdf->Output($Filename, 'F');
        }
        catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
            echo $e;
            exit;
        }
 $content_print .= ob_get_clean(); // add the content for the next document and now delete the output buffer 

   echo "<br> $name ...done!";
    echo str_pad('',4096)."\n";    //display some results so the page won't stay blank for too long
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    }
echo "all done!";
```