# bulk pdf generation with html2pdf in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, html2pdf

I am using HTML2PDF library in codeigniter.I am trying to generate bulk pdf using it.

In which i am facing issue like same content in every pdf or pdf have no content.I have already did my homework.Yeah but there is always showing perfect for generated first pdf (For account :3)

As per me there is must be issue of below code :

```
    ob_start();
    require_once($template_config.'template.php'); // 
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_clean();
```

Issue : It works for first time but for second time it flush all the content of content variable and due to that duplicate PDF or without content PDF generate.

I have tried like below

1) create object in generatetemplate.php and pass to common.php

2) tried with include_once //getting same conent in every pdf and if i am doing echo then showing no content for 2nd and 3rd pdf

```
File structure : 
   application
      controllers
          generatetemplate.php
      libraries
          common.php
          html2pdf
              html2pdf.php
      template.php


common.php :

function print_content($customerdata){
    $this->load->library('/html2pdf/html2pdf');
    $template_config=$this->config->item('template');
    ob_start();
    require_once($template_config.'template.php'); // 
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_clean();
    $content = str_replace("<CUSTOMER_ADDRESS>",$CUSTOMER_ADDRESS,$content);
    $this->CI->html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    $this->CI->html2pdf->writeHTML($content);
    $this->CI->html2pdf->Output($download_path,"F");
 }

generatetemplate.php
     function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->load->library("common");
       $this->load->library('html2pdf');
     }
     function get_customer_data(){
       $this->db->order_by("id","DESC");
       $this->db->where('id IN (1,2,3)');
       $query = $this->db->get("customers")->result_array();
       foreach($query as $key=>$accountdata){
         $this->common->print_content($accountdata);
       }
     }
```

Any help and ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: It seems, maybe, you are loading `html2pdf` library twice (i.e. in `generatetemplate.php` and in `common.php`)?

Comment: hav a look in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32225465/multiple-pdf-files-with-html2pdf

Comment: @safinchacko yeah i have tried that one already but not working

Comment: i have add one line in above code and its working for me now. let me paste my answer here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried below code and its work for me.

Common.php

```
function print_content($customerdata){
    $this->load->library('/html2pdf/html2pdf');
    $template_config=$this->config->item('template');
    ob_start();
    require_once($template_config.'template.php'); // 
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_clean();
    $content = str_replace("<CUSTOMER_ADDRESS>",$CUSTOMER_ADDRESS,$content);
    $this->CI->html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','en'); // Just added this line and its work for me.
    $this->CI->html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    $this->CI->html2pdf->writeHTML($content);
    $this->CI->html2pdf->Output($download_path,"F");
 }
```